# Can I make a list option unselectable in Google Forms?

Tags: google-forms, list

Similar to the HTML `<option>` attribute `disable`, I want to make a Google Forms list have some options that are visible but unelectable. Is this possible?

Comment: Can try with jquery here check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10570070/how-to-disable-enable-select-field-using-jquery

Comment: @Vembu This is for a Google-Form. How can I use jQuery with a Google Forms list?

Comment: Here check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351188/can-i-submit-form-info-to-google-spreadsheets-with-jquerys-ajax